# Converting linux commands with os.popen in python

Tags: python, linux, popen

How i can make this command:

```
ACTIVE_MGMT_1=`ssh -n ${MGMT_IP_1}  ". .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*" 2>/dev/null |egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2`;
```

run through python?

I was trying to do:

```
active_mgmgt_1 = os.popen("""ssh -n MGMT_IP_1  ". .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*" 2>/dev/null |egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2""")
SITE_NAME = site_name.read().replace('\n', '')
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) with `shell=True`:

```
cmd = r'''ssh -n ${MGMT_IP_1} ". .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*" 2>/dev/null |egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2'''
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

**UPDATE**

`subprocess.check_output` was added in Python 2.7. If you use older version of Python, Use [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, errmsg = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: >>> cmd = r'''ssh -n ${MGMT_IP_1} ". .bash_profile; xms sho proc TRAF.*" 2>/dev/null |egrep " A " |awk '/TRAF/{print $1}' |cut -d "." -f2'''
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: @user3013012, Which version of python do you use?

Comment: @user3013012, I updated the answer with an alternative solution. Check  it out.